# Can I run WebAssembly inside a PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, webassembly

So, you can run Javascript inside a PDF file but with a completely different library than your browser (if even implemented by your PDF reader).

Knowing this, and in the spirit of pushing further the crazy things we can do with PDF, could we run WebAssembly from inside a PDF?

Comment: It would likely depend on what JS engine is embedded in the PDF reading client.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why should that be good? The past has shown that an overloaded PDF client is pretty vulnerable, so why not focus on PDF as a document format?

Comment: @Nico How else will you run Doom within a PDF?

Comment: Why should I? There are way better ways to play games than within a PDF reader

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot run WebAssembly inside a PDF. While PDF supports JavaScript, it supports only the JavaScript core with its own object model riding on top of that. I haven't found any frameworks that will function in that environment.